# How do I combine templates from different HTML files

Tags: knockout.js

Since Knockout's individual templates are kept in script tags, I thought that I could set the `src` attribute of the tag and load the HTML from a separate file.  Doing so naïvely simply didn't work, so either

1. There's some trick to getting the binding of templates to work with `src` tag that I need to use
2. There's a different way to load templates from different files

(The other two possibilities -- 3, all the programmers on this project are expected to modify the same gigantic file, which will be loaded by the browser on start-up, and 4, don't use Knockoutjs for anything larger than a toy project -- I consider equivalent.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A browser won't respond to `src` on anything that has a type other than one of the various 'javascript' types and with those it will try to execute the result as a script.

Several options though:

- use a template engine that can pull templates remotely (the best one is here: https://github.com/ifandelse/Knockout.js-External-Template-Engine).
- Loop on your script tags that contain templates and load them up.  Something like this would pull the contents using the `src` as the location.  You would need to be careful of when you call applyBindings, if your templates aren't ready.

  ```
  $("script[type='text/html']").each(function(index, el) { $.get($(el).attr("src"),
      function(response) {
          $(el).text(response); });
  });
  ```
- Here are some other options that I looked at for doing this a while back: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/using-external-jquery-template-files.html

Answer (score 1):

Each template in my project is its own html file. I use a naming convention (*.ko.html) to identify them.
My build chain goes like this:

**Step 1: Lint and minify *.ko.html files** 
This is just to remove comments (except `<!-- ko -->` ones) and strip extra whitespace for a more compact payload.

**Step 2: Stringify and concat minified html into a js file.**
The js looks something like

```
var templates={
  'name1':'some stringified html',
  'name2':'some more'
};
```

I did consider concatenating into an html file with `<script type="text/plain">` delimiters but chose js because this way it can be loaded using a simple `<script>` tag instead of an ajax get + inject.

**Step 3: Fix up the native template engine to retrieve templates from my js object.**

```
var engine = new ko.nativeTemplateEngine();
engine._makeTemplateSource = engine.makeTemplateSource;

engine.makeTemplateSource = function (template, doc) {        
    if (typeof (template) === 'string' && templates[template]) {
        return { text: function () { return templates[template]; } };
    }
    return engine._makeTemplateSource(template, doc);
};
ko.setTemplateEngine(engine);
```

My implementation uses gruntjs to perform these build steps. (grunt-contrib-htmlmin, grunt-contrib-concat)

options for htmlmin:

```
{
removeComments: true, 
collapseWhitespace: true, 
ignoreCustomComments: [/^\s*ko /, /^\s*\/ko /] 
}
```

options for concat

```
{
  stripBanners: true,
  banner: "(function(t){",
  footer: "})(window.templates || (window.templates={}));",
  process: function (src, file) {
      return 't[\'' + file.replace(/^.*\//, '').replace('.ko.html', '') + '\']=' + JSON.stringify(src) + ';';
  }
}
```

For anyone wondering why anyone would want to do this:
Template source files are standard individual html files that can be edited in any html editor and source controlled as such. Editting html inside `<script>` tags is no fun. As a bonus, source files can include comments that will be stripped out.
Templates are re-usable on any page by including the script tag: they don't need to be inlined into every page.
The resulting bundle is a static file that browsers can easily cache, while templates embedded into a dynamically generated page can't.
Pretty much the same reasons for bundling javascript files.

Comment: hey do you have an online repository with a sample e.g. on github?